# Extracting an inline JavaScript onclick-function with a paramater to an external js file

Tags: javascript

I have the following elements:

```
<th id="fileName" onclick="sortBy(this.id)">Datei&emsp;</th>
```

and would like to extract the js function sortBy(this.id) in an extarnal js-file and call it there by attaching an event-handler, something like this:

```
document.getElementById("fileName").addEventListener('click', sortBy);
```

but how and where to put the parameter `this.id`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the parameter "this.id" to the sortBy() function when you call it in the event handler. The code would look like this:

```js
document.getElementById("fileName").addEventListener('click', function(){sortBy(this.id);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the function something like the below:

```
function sortBy(myId) {
    console.log(myId);
}
```

Now you can call the same function as below:

```
document.getElementById("fileName").addEventListener('click', function(){sortBy(this.id);});
```

Comment: you can also use like this:
`document.getElementById("fileName").addEventListener('click', sortBy);`